# "Слишком много хочешь" - фразеологизм или нет?

Tags: фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли считать фразу "слишком много хочешь" устойчивым фразеологизмом?

Comment: @meltar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен. Обычно, "фразеологизм" выделяют в тех случаях, когда значение фразы отличается от суммы значений слов... В данном случае ничего подобного не наблюдается.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем получить высокое звание
   фразеологизма, речение долго тащит службу в качестве устойчивого сочетания )))